# Unit testing, is it a good idea to verify methods are not called

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

Let's say you've got the following method to test:

```
public void foo(object myObject, bool myBool)
{
     if(myBool)
        repositoryA.save(myObject)
     else
        repositoryB.save(myObject)
}
```

What is the best way to unit test such a function? If you write 2 tests 
 that assert repositoryA is called when myBool is true, and repositoryB is called when myBool is false, then the following change to the function would still make the tests pass but would potentially break the functionality of the application:

```
public void foo(object myObject, bool myBool)
{
    repositoryA.save(myObject)
    repositoryB.save(myObject)
}
```

On the other hand, if you assert that when myBool is true then repositoryA is called AND that repositoryB is not called, that gives you more confidence that any change to the function will not introduce bugs, but then you have a test which depends on implementation details. What's the best way to do it?

And what if you use TDD, what tests would you write in order the reach the desired functionality?

Comment: If you test that one of the repository is called and find that normal, then calling the repository is not an implementation detail. And testing that a repository is not called is thus not testing an implementation detail. That said: a test should not cover all potential weird stuff someone could do in the code. If you find the potential breakage has a reasonable probability to happen, then add that assertion. Otherwise, don't. but remember that the developer breaking the test might change the code of the test too anyway. The bast call would probably to have two methods rather than one.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense

Comment: Maybe it's not your case, because your example is somewhat "incomplete"; I mean: having a better naming could help in this dissertation.

Anyway: it seems that your implementation is hiding a polymorphism (I'm referring to the boolean parameter that change the internal behaviour).

So, if you ask me "if you use TDD", I would answer you that having that kind of contract it's a little bit strange. I think that you could have two different implementation of the same Repository interface.

But, again, I really don't know what "myBool" is, so this could be a legitimate case.

Comment: I can't modify the contract, and in my case i actually have 9-10 parameters that can each influence what i need to do, persist in repoA, persist in repoB, call a web api, do nothing, The logic is actually really complicated because of it. I asked the question with a simplified example.

Comment: Test behaviour not implementations. This way you can change the implementation without altering the tests - Refactoring with confidence. TDD will help design your code in a testable, behaviour driven way.

Comment: @MikeJ, is not calling some method part of the behavior that should be tested?

Comment: @chocoman - I would say that's testing the implementation not the outcome. This tightly couples tests and the production code. Refactoring the production code may then need the test to be updated, which is risky when changing both parts. You lose the regression test. In my view where possible its best to test the expected outcome without knowing the implementation details. This is where TDD comes in, as the test would be written before you have any implementation. I accept it may not always possible, but that would be my aim. The key thing however you do it, is to make sure its a good test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way to unit test such a function?

Start by redesigning it?

Part of the point of developing test first is the claim that testable interfaces are also "better"; more easily consumed, more easily maintained.

So the point you (correctly) raise about testing the side effects of this method is a "design smell" -- it's a hint that maybe this code design isn't the one you need for your use case.

Two possibilities:

One is that the code is trying to tell you that you have a telemetry requirement; that you should be able to query the system under test and learn how many objects have been saved to each repository, or what the last object saved to each repository was, or something along those lines.

Then you can leverage the telemetry to write your test

```
Given:
    telemetry reports that repository B has stored 7 objects
    and myBool is true
When:
    foo()
Then:
    telemetry reports that repository B has stored 7 objects
```

This basically cracks the problem into two pieces; a collection of tests that ensure that the telemetry accurately reports the number of times a repository has saved the object, and then a test of `foo()` that assumes the telemetry is working.

Second alternative: the test is trying to tell you that you want to be able to evaluate which side effects are happening in the program.  So make those effects a first class citizen in your design, and write tests that check the effects.

```
List<Effect> foo () {
    if (myBool) {
        return List.of(SaveInRepositoryA);
    } else {
        return List.of(SaveInRepositoryB);
    }
}
```

Now your assertion is easier - you just make sure the List has the right number of elements in it, and the correct elements.

Important note: what these designs are doing is creating a seam between your logic and the side effects.  Imagine a boundary, on one side of the boundary is complicated logic that is easy to test, because it's all manipulations of data in memory; on the other side of the boundary is code that is hard to test, but so simple and straight forward that it obviously doesn't have any bugs.

Comment: I really like your second approach. It also seems to scale well if your logic gets more complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to your question (please read also my comment, could be valuable more generally speaking), I would write something like that: (using JMock, a Java mocking library)

```
// with myBool == true

context.checking(new Expectations(){{
    oneOf(repositoryA).save(object);
    never(repositoryB);
}});

underTest.foo(object, true);




// with myBool == false

context.checking(new Expectations(){{
    never(repositoryA);
    oneOf(repositoryB).save(object);
}});

underTest.foo(object, false);
```